# Is there a way to concatenate specific files in the folder along with folder names in python

Tags: python

In my project directory there are 2 folders called datafiles and templates. Under each folder, there are files

```
templates 
--- street1_bangalore_ind.json
--- street1_mysore_ind.json
--- street2_bangalore_ind.json
--- street21_bangalore_ind.json

datafiles 
--- street3_bangalore_ind.json
--- street4_mysore_ind.json
--- street4_bangalore_ind.json
--- street41_bangalore_ind.json
```

I only need street1, street2, street3 and street4 from Bangalore to be considered. So it should concatenate with the respective directory

Expected output

```
['templates/street1_bangalore_ind.json', 'templates/street2_bangalore_ind.json', 
'datafiles/street3_bangalore_ind.json', 'datafiles/street4_bangalore_ind.json']
```

I tried with following code but got stuck. Can anyone help?

```
import os
fol = ['datafiles', 'templates']
for i in fol:
    print(i+str(os.listdir(i)))
```

Comment: `for filename in os.listdir(i):print(os.path.join(i,filename))` you need to iterate over the listdir call

Comment: "but got stuck": Please elaborate.

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks. It worked. But I need only specific strings? Please see my question :)

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would isolate filenames containing 'bangalore' or the appendages '1', '2', '3' or '4'

Answer (score 0):

I think [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) should work for you.

You can try something like this when run from the same directory as your `templates` and `datafiles` folders or you can specify the root directory.

```
import glob
lst = glob.glob('./*/street[1,2,3,4]_bangalore*.json')
```

I only created a couple files but the output should something like

```
['./templates/street3_bangalore_ind.json',
 './datafiles/street1_bangalore_ind.json']
```

Comment: Probably better to have discrete searches for files in the templates and datafile directories because of the possibility of other directories existing with the same filenames e.g., './temp/street1_bangalore_ind.json'

Comment: Yes, OP can replace `./*/` with whatever works best for them based on how the root directory is set up.